# Fast Dynamic MVT generation

Tags: postgis, tiles, vector-tiles, mbtiles, tippecanoe

I am trying to migrate from serving static MVT to generated on the backend by PostGIS with *ST_AsMVT()*. Or find a way of minimizing the time of building MVT from the database.

I have a dataset of political, historical maps, and I am serving them as prerendered Mapbox Vector Tiles. Dataset itself is not massive. It's 2300 entities for 200 years ~ 1Gb of data. As a result, distant zoom tile (**/1/0/0**) has ~ 600 geometries. They are filtered on client side with filter option by year in MVT style. We want to introduce an ability for the end-user to upload their maps.

Pipeline to produce an MVT tileset that we are using right now:

1. Loop over geometry in the database and dump it in a file as a GeoJSON feature (feature collection does not fit into memory)
2. Process output with tippecanoe and zoom up to 10
3. Serve file.mbtiles with mbtiles-server

It took around 30 minutes and full CPU load for the whole cycle.

As one way of optimization here - we could rebuild only the part that was changed and update tileset with *tile-join*

---

I've tried to serve MVT directly from PostGIS with *ST_AsMVT()*,
Geometry is in SRID:4326 queries were executed with similar simplification level and against the same bounding box **/1/0/0**

Full queries and explanation are [here](https://github.com/chronhq/backend/pull/138#issuecomment-507324216)

- The straight-forward approach of MVT generation took 130-177 seconds
- Simplification after transforming to SRID:3857 (WebMercator) took 30 seconds
- Simplification before processing to SRID:3857 took 3 seconds

```sql
-- three seconds to execute
SELECT ST_AsMVT(a, 'stv')
FROM (
  SELECT
      api_spacetimevolume.id
      , api_spacetimevolume.start_date::INTEGER
      , api_spacetimevolume.end_date::INTEGER
      , api_spacetimevolume.references
      , ST_AsMVTGeom(
          ST_SnapToGrid(
            ST_Transform(
              ST_Simplify(
                  api_spacetimevolume.territory
                , 0.44 -- Dynamic based on zoom level
              )
              , 3857
            )
            , 1
          )
          , TileBBox(1, 0, 0)
      ) as territory
      , api_spacetimevolume.entity_id
      , api_territorialentity.wikidata_id
      , api_territorialentity.color
      , api_territorialentity.admin_level
  FROM api_spacetimevolume
  JOIN api_territorialentity
  ON api_spacetimevolume.entity_id = api_territorialentity.id
  WHERE territory && TileBBox(1, 0, 0, 4326)
) as a
;
```

Even with 3 seconds per tile, it is obvious that it should be cached on disk or in the database. Temporary caching (nginx or redis) will not solve the problem completely.

In this [article](https://www.zimmi.cz/posts/2017/serving-mapbox-vector-tiles-with-postgis-nginx-and-python-backend/) Michal Zimmerman is generating tiles in advance by PostGis and storing them on disk.

---

Well, the questions

1. What do you recommend to speed up the tile delivery?
2. What is the best way to keep the tile generation flexible?

Comment: Have you tried using GeoServer. There is an mbtiles plugin and GeoWebcache will do this out of the box -- ie, pre-generate the tiles, if you want, but also provide a built-in caching mechanism. The source would still be Postgres/Postgis, but this is likely to be a lot quicker than using ST_AsMVT on the fly.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at GeoServer, we are using [mbtiles-server](https://github.com/DenisCarriere/mbtiles-server) at this moment. It was a convenient way when we picked it for almost a year ago.

Comment: Is mbtiles-server slow then? Geoserver won't necessarily be any quicker, it is just that it works out of the box and gives you a lot of other options to.

Comment: mbtiles-server is fast, but we need to process tiles before they will be served. So we are extracting everything from postgis to geojson file, then processing geojson with tippecanoe.

Comment: Take a look to [pg_tileserv](https://github.com/CrunchyData/pg_tileserv)

Answer (score 0):

I can only hint at question one, but according to this arctile https://carto.com/blog/MVT-mapnik-vs-postgis/

> "We may also consider removing the ST_Simplify and ST_SnapToGrid as
> they aim to facilitate raster rendering and it’s done by the MVT
> encoding mechanism."